# Variable database name for ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am creating a custom ContentProvider in Android, all the examples I find show the database name being hardcoded, instantiated like this:

```
public class ItemProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private static String DATABASE_NAME = "xyz";

    public static class ItemDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    ItemDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }
```

What I want to do is use a variable for the database name at runtime, I dont want to hard code the database name in the class. I have tried to find examples of doing this using the ContentProvider class, and have looked through the documentation as well. I can do this if I shed the ContentProvider class and just use a SQLiteOpenHelper class because I can pass in the database name to the constructor as a parameter but I cannot figure out if its possible for ContentProvider. Here is how I get a variable name for the database using SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
public static class ItemDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    ItemDatabaseHelper(Context context, String dbname) {
        super(context, dbname, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

Can anyone help me get a variable database name for a Content Provider?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've not really used ContentProviders myself, but looking at the docs I'm guessing the root of the problem is that you don't instantiate the ContentProvider yourself, but that Android does when it is needed to handle a request.

If you want the database name to be defined at runtime by your application, then you could simply use a public static variable, which you set appropriately from another part of your application. You could then reference this from your `ContentProvider`.

Alternatively, if you're wanting the person who requests something from the `ContentProvider` to be able to specify the database to query, then from the docs it looks like you could use the path of the request URI to specify the database to query.

The structure of the request URI is detailed here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html#urisum and further up this page it says:

> The authority is what identifies the provider, not the path; your provider can interpret the path part of the URI in any way you choose.

So as an example, I would imagine you could use an URI of the form:

`content://com.example.yourprovider/DB_REF/ID`

Then in your implementation of the abstract methods of `ContentProvider` you could parse the URI to determine the DB to use.

**One word of warning though** - if you are going to use this approach, then I would suggest not using the value passed in directly. It would be much better to use some kind of validation against a finite list, so that people can't just query any of your databases (if they know their name).

Hopefully that makes sense :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are correct about the way ContentProviders are instantiated, its all "automatic" which is why I dont have control at the SQLiteOpenHelper level. I don't think your second suggestion would work because I need to have multiple identically structured databases on the device and the user needs to be able to switch between them at runtime, plus I dont know what they will be called in advance. Your first suggestion sounds good and I have tried to implement it but my Java skills aren't up to it, how would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

First, let me say that I've looked at lots of examples for ContentProvider code on the web, and the one that ended up helping me the most was this one:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_content-providers/

I have a very similar situation to yours, where I want to have several differently-named databases containing vehicle fuel mileage data.  Each of the names consists of a vehicle name (specified by the user) and the current year, plus the fixed text "fuel_data" to make the database filenames human-readable.

Unlike all of the examples I found, I do not create an instance of the database in the ContentProvider's onCreate method.  This is because I don't yet know the vehicle name at that point, thanks to the way my code is written (and the fact that ContentProviders are instantiated so early in the Activity lifecycle).

Once I do know the vehicle name (from which I can easily construct the database name), I call a simple little method that I added to my ContentProvider class.  As you can see, all it does is close the prior database (if one was open) and open the new one (using the name that I now have available).

I call this method again every time the user selects a new vehicle.

`    private static FuelDatabase mDB = null;

```
 public static void switchDatabases( Context context, String newVehicleName )
 {
     if ( mDB != null )
     {
     mbB.close();
     }

     mDB = new FuelDatabase( context, newVehicleName + "." + getCurrentYear( context ) );
 }`
```